# "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor" error

Tags: java

I am trying to make a constructor that takes a string and constructs a date object. This is my solution so far but I am getting this error:

> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

```
private int m;
private int d;
private int y;
private String[] dateStrings;

public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
          m = month;
          d = day;
          y = year;  
  }

public Date(String s) {
      dateStrings = s.split("/");
      this(Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[2]));
  }
```

I realize I need `this(...)` before everything but how can I do that when I need to populate dateStrings first?
How can I avoid this error?
Note: to construct a date with a string it is in the format of "month/day/year"

Comment: `this(...)` should be the first line inside the constructor.

Comment: But then how can it be contructed without first populating `dateStrings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this()` needs to be called first.

Instead move the assignment to a private method.

```
private void assginValues (int month, int day, int year){
          m = month;
          d = day;
          y = year;  
}
```

If you also need `dateStrings` populated, you can build it in this method too.

Then call the method from both constructors. Make sure that the constructor accepting a String does not call `this()` since the shared method takes care of assigning the values.

You can also do everything in one line, but then you call `split()` multiple times which is ***wasteful***:

```
this(Integer.parseInt(s.split("/")[0]), Integer.parseInt(s.split("/")[1]), Integer.parseInt(s.split("/")[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to avoid it is to use a static factory

```
public static Date MakeDate(String s) {
  dateStrings = s.split("/");
  return new Date(Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[1]),  
     Integer.parseInt(dateStrings[2]));
 }
```

And for constencies sake, I might overload this and just avoid the whole weirdness of having one factory and one constructor.

```
 private Date(int month, int day, int year) {
      m = month;
      d = day;
      y = year;  
  }

 public static MakeDate(int mont, int day, int year){
      //You can figure this part out
 }
```

A nice bonus of this is that you can name these factories differently to make their intent clear. Probably not necessary in this case but it's a nice option to have, especially with more complex classes.